# Excel 1004 on for loop

Tags: excel, vba

Why on Earth does this keep giving me 1004? The Worksheet Name and Codename is the same, so it can reference it, so why do I keep getting the 1004

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim coLoc As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ia As Integer

coLoc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Company").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).count
For i = 2 To coLoc Step 1
ComboBox1.AddItem (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Company").Cells(i, 2).Value)
Next i   

End Sub
```

Please give me some clarity, as the keyboard is going to go through the screen.

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it but I assume it crashes when you assign a value to Coloc.
VBA doesn't know which "cells" you are talking about. I know it may sound counter-intuitive, but you need to specify that inside the Range, and not before.

Try :

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Company")
    coLoc = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).count
End With
```

Comment: Probably also should qualify your `Rows` object :)

Comment: Ahah, didn't even pay attention to that one. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's raising this particular error without more detail, but try fully qualifying your range objects.

This uses a slightly different iteration method:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb as Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Company")
    Dim colRange as Range
    Dim cl as Range


    Set colRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
    For each cl in colRange.Cells
        ComboBox1.AddItem cl.Value
    Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for fully qualifying the `Cells` objects. very important and an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, I like to use `List` to populate a combobox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim colRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Company")
    Set colRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    ComboBox1.List = colRange.Value
End Sub
```

There is no need to qualify `Rows.Count`, although it does no harm.

Comment: +1 I always forget about the `.List` method!  Maybe if I see it around S/O more often I'll remember it :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you. I don't think many are aware of it (or they aren't sure how to assign it). BTW I'm curious why you are using `colRange.Cells` ?

Comment: `.cells` isn't necessary in this case because the range is only one column but it would accommodate a multicolumn range.  I try to be eexplicit rather than implicit :)